# How to get smooth scrolling without taking time in loading video in tik tok clone app in flutter

Tags: flutter, caching, flutter-video-player, tiktok, instagram-reels

Here is my code

first of all I make list of all videos Info and urls
and then make list view of video player
and pass these urls one by one to video player of each video according to their index in the list.

1. this is video urls array

```
List<String> AllVideosUrls = [
           "videoUrl1",
           "videoUrl2",
           "videoUrl3",
           "videoUrl3",
           "videoUrl4",
]
```

2. this is list view of video player

```
return PageView.builder(
            itemCount: AllVideosUrls.length,
            controller: PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 1),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              final eachVideoUrl = AllVideosUrls[index];

              return VideoPlayer(
                      videoFileUrl: eachVideoUrl()
                      );
              }
             ),
            )
```

3. this is video player widget

```
class VideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoFileUrl;

  const HomeVideoPlayer({
    super.key,
    required this.videoFileUrl,
  });

  @override
  State<VideoPlayer> createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}

class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayer> {

  VideoPlayerController? playerController;

  bool isPlayerInitialized = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    playerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoFileUrl)
      ..initialize().then((value) {
        setState(() {
          isPlayerInitialized = false;
        });

        playerController!.play();
        playerController!.setLooping(true);
        playerController!.setVolume(2);
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    playerController!.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: playerController!.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(playerController!),
                ),
              ),
            );
           }
         }
```

I want that the videos should download already when I watch present video so this reduce the loading when we scroll up to next video.

Comment: There are many different source that explain such integration - e.g https://medium.com/@sanjeevmadhav03/preloading-videos-in-flutter-4b65cf0681c6